# using function as parameter - issues

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JS:

```
if (Subs.Lsr!==null) {
   Subs.Measure.Do("markLSRPosts",function() {
      Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce);
   });
}
```

Because this kind of code is inside my file multiple times I wanted to create a function for that:

```
function SingleMeasure(measureTitle, functionName) {
    if (setting!==null) {
        Subs.Measure.Do(measureTitle,function() {
            functionName();   
        });
    }
}
SingleMeasure(Subs.Lsr, "markLSRPosts", Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce));
```

Now my problem is that the function `Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce)` is called BEFORE my `SingleMeasure()`-Function is called (and so always, no matter what the condition of `setting` is).

I have to admit: This makes sense to me from coding logic. Nonetheless I wonder if there is another way to achieve what I want. (the method `...Dom()` only being called when the `setting`-condition is met)

Comment: BTW: If anyone can think of a better title to this problem, feel free to modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my problem is that the function Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce) is called BEFORE my SingleMeasure()

That's because you are calling it right here: `Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce)`

```
SingleMeasure(Subs.Lsr, "markLSRPosts", Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce));
```

You might pass it as an anonymous function:

```
SingleMeasure(Subs.Lsr, "markLSRPosts", function() { 
    Subs.Lsr.Dom($ce); 
});
```

The callback will be invoked by your `SingleMeasure` function at a later stage.

Comment: Could .bind be used here as well?